# How to extract the following address using regex?

Tags: regex

im having trouble coming out with a regex that meets all 3 addresses. Currently it only extracts one line. Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

**Address**

```
place1
8 Raffles Avenue, #01-02/04 Singapore 039802

place2
1 Harbourfront Walk
#02-94 
Singapore 098585

place3
1 Harbourfront Walk #02-94 
Singapore 098585
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XAj397/2

Comment: what just happened? its the same regex with an extra space?

Comment: regex101.com/r/XAj397/3  simplify to \d+ .*Singapore\s+\d{6}\b  is this what you want?

Comment: This is perfect! how to do i extract the title as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\w.+\d+ .+Singapore\s+\d{6}/Ugs
```

https://regex101.com/r/XAj397/5

Comment: im sorry i wanted to capture the title seperately. sorry for the trouble `(.+?)\s*(\d+ .*Singapore\s+\d{6}\b)\b` this is what i have in mind but just having trouble detecting the address